# Disabling Marker on menu-item with sub-items [Wordpress]

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I can't seem to figure out how to remove marker on menu items that have sub-items, like this for example:

www.garffgroup.com

The menu item "about" is always marked with an underline, how can I disable that? I already tried adding custom class just for that item and editing in css, but to no avail, or maybe I used the wrong code.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: Please paste the CSS that you are using currently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add below style in your style.css file

```
a.menu-item-link:after {
    background: transparent !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because of CSS rule written for menu items' :after selectors. You can add this CSS which removes that part:

```
.menu-item-link:after {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0) !important;
}
```